# Remove number prefix from lot of files

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I have some 50 songs which starts with a number, like this:

[image]

It is hard to rename each file manually to remove the number prefix part. Example, `06-` part from the file name. Is there any other way to remove these numbers?

I tried using CLI:

```
for %a in (*.*) do @set "fname=%a" & call ren "%fname%" "/s/^\d\s-/"
```

I know it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remove number prefix from lot of files**

The below batch script should do the trick for you. Just set your sourcedir to the applicable folder where the MP3 file exist, save the logic to a text document but rename it to give it a file extension of .cmd, and then double click on it to run and rename the files accordingly.

```
@ECHO ON

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET SourceDir=C:\Users\User\Desktop\songs

FOR /F "TOKENS=2 DELIMS=-" %%F IN ('DIR /B /A-D "%SourceDir%\*.mp3"') DO (  
    REN "%SourceDir%\*%%~F" "%%~F"
)
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN ('DIR /B /A-D "%SourceDir%\*.mp3"') DO (
    REN "%SourceDir%\*%%~F" "%%~F"
)
GOTO EOF
```

---

### Further Resources

- [**FOR /F**](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [**Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion**](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [**REN**](http://ss64.com/nt/ren.html)